# Restore values on screen rotation

Tags: android

I have created several TextViews programmatically. When screen rotates I loose all added text views and their text values. What is the best way to save them and restore after rotation. I am using a tablelayout and adding rows each row has four textviews. I did not want to prevent device rotation.

Comment: From the documentation, it seems to me that dynamically created views should still save their state automatically. However you need to restore your model, and if you update the views from the models, it will look like they didn't get saved. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29

Comment: TextViews aren't automatically saved, because they're not editable by the user. However, EditTexts do get saved. I've got burned by that as well.

Answer (score 5):

You should use onSaveInstanceState to save your state, and then recreate it in onCreate. This works for both Activities and Fragments, but I believe the visibility on the methods is a bit different (they're public for Fragments).

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("text1", text1.getText().toString());
    // do this for each of your text views
    // You might consider using Bundle.putStringArray() instead
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // initialize all your visual fields        

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        text1.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("text1", ""));
        // do this for each of your text views
    }
}
```

Note that this is better than using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance; that method is used to actually keep objects around across rotations (e.g. Bitmaps), however you want to just store the strings, and thus using a Bundle is preferred. Also, onRetainNonConfigurationInstance isn't supported by Fragments; it's been replaced with setRetainInstance, and you don't want to use that for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to persist the state across Device Rotation. As your view gets created dynamically, you need to store all this information in a 'Model' appropriate for your application. Android developer website has more info.

"To retain an object during a runtime configuration change:

Override the onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() method to return the object you would like to retain.
When your activity is created again, call getLastNonConfigurationInstance() to recover your object."

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject

Comment: onRetainNonConfigurationInstance is used to actually keep objects around across rotations (e.g. Bitmaps), and I don't think that's what the OP really wants. Also, onRetainNonConfigurationInstance isn't supported by Fragments; it's been replaced with setRetainInstance, and you don't want to use that for the same reason.