# Fragment not loading landscape layout when device rotates, reverts back to previous fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragment

I am having trouble with a fragment not calling the landscape layout of itself. When you rotate the device, it reverts back to the previous fragment and puts this into the logcat:

A breakdown:

I am in Fragment A, press a button and am taken to Fragment B. When I rotate the device, Fragment A is shown in landscape view.

> requestLayout() improperly called by android.widget.ListView{43a67d00 VFED.VC. ......ID 0,0-720,1845} during layout: running second layout pass
>
> E/ViewRootImpl﹕ sendUserActionEvent() mView == null

If the device has already been rotated and the fragment is then selected, the landscape layout loads fine, it is just whilst you are in the fragment itself.

Here is the code for the fragment, I hope you can help!

```
public class nandos_Fragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    View rootview;
    MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    public static Button scanBtn;
    public static int retrievedResult = 0;
    private static final String TAG = "MyActivity";
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.nandos_layout, container, false);
    scanBtn = (Button) rootview.findViewById(R.id.scan_button);
    scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    mMapView = (MapView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mMapView.onResume();// needed to get the map to display immediately
    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    googleMap = mMapView.getMap();
    // latitude and longitude
    double latitude = 52.955491;
    double longitude = -1.149885;

    // create marker
    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(
            new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("Nandos Nottingham!");

    // Changing marker icon
    marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));

    // adding marker
    googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(new LatLng(52.955491, -1.149885)).zoom(15).build();
    googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
            .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
    return rootview;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    //respond to clicks
    if (v.getId() == R.id.scan_button) {
        //scan
        if (retrievedResult == 0) {
            IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(getActivity());
            scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }else{}

    }
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
    Random r = new Random();
    int i1 = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;
    if (result != null) {
        scanBtn.setText("Code: " + result + i1);
        retrievedResult = 1;
    }

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
    scanBtn.setText("Get Offer!");
    retrievedResult = 0;
    result = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.v(TAG, "ON DESTROY");
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.user.ntuio" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.ram.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ntsu"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_nav_bar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="****"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Can you post your Manifest file.

Comment: Also, take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533693/app-shows-main-screen-after-screen-rotation

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks for the reply, what should i be saving the state of in particular? what is causing this error to occur?

Answer (score -1):

Add
`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`
after
`android:label="@string/title_activity_nav_bar"`
That should prevent the refreshing after rotating the device.

Comment: This means that the activity will not reload, and therefore won't open the landscape layout. I need the landscape layout to load.

Comment: unfortunately that hasn't fixed it, it still reverts back to the previous fragment